# Quizlet API Error "setAction called with null action"?

Tags: python, api

I am trying to make a script in Python using the Quizlet API that searches sets with a specific term in it. The only problem is is that I get this error:

`{"http_code":400,"error":"client_developer_error","error_title":"Error","error_description":"setAction called with null action"}`

Here is the script:

```
import requests
import os

id = ''
key = ''

def err_fill_out():
    print '[-] Please fill out your terms.txt file'
    exit(1)

if os.path.exists('terms.txt'):
    print '[*] Found terms.txt ...'
    terms = [i.strip() for i in open('terms.txt', 'r+').readlines()]
    if len(terms) == 0:
        err_fill_out()

    for i in terms:
        print '[*] Looking for best term of', i, '...'
        r = requests.post(url='https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/search/sets', data={"client_id": id, "access_token": key, "term": i, "sort": "most_studied"})
        print r.text
else:
    open('terms.txt', 'w+')
    err_fill_out()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your request isn't quite right. Am not sure how you're getting that error with the code you posted.

Check the documentation page again: https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/searching-sets

A couple things:

- should be a `get`
- requires the parameter `q` rather than `term`
- `sort` has been depreciated

I was able to get results with this line:

```
r = requests.get(url='https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/search/sets', params={"client_id": id, "access_token": key, "q": i})
```